How to create a detector for random objects detection using dlib?
According to the source of train_object_detector.py, dlib is useful for creating an object detector based on the .xml database were images are annotated for detecting a specific object, as the docs state:
training_xml_path = os.path.join(faces_folder, "training.xml")
testing_xml_path = os.path.join(faces_folder, "testing.xml")
# This function does the actual training.  It will save the final detector to
# detector.svm.  The input is an XML file that lists the images in the training
# dataset and also contains the positions of the face boxes.  To create your
# own XML files you can use the imglab tool which can be found in the
# tools/imglab folder.  It is a simple graphical tool for labeling objects in
# images with boxes.  To see how to use it read the tools/imglab/README.txt
# file.  But for this example, we just use the training.xml file included with
# dlib.
dlib.train_simple_object_detector(training_xml_path, "detector.svm", options)

But how could I create a random object detector without using any database/XML files to generate an svm model that detects every object in a given image, is that even possible?
Is it that each detector.svm should be about a single specific object? or could I train using .xml file that contains different images labeled differently for different objects detection?
